# How to check for the same ID, and then increment for that particular id?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a hashmap, let's call it `hashMap`, that is in a method whereby I'll pass in a string called `id`. I also have an object, let's call it `UserObject`. So currently what I want to do is write my output to a csv file, using the below code:

```
for (UserObject user: hashMap.get(id)) {
            System.out.println(id);
            writer.println(id + "," + user.getTime() + "," + user.getLat() + "," + user.getLng()); // csv
        }
```

but this id may have multiples of the same one. So what I wanna do is whenever one id is used for the for loop, there'll be a counter that increments by one. So, when the same id is used again, the increment will increase. However, when a different id is being used, it is another increment operation. So basically what I mean is that whenever the for loop is running I want to count how many instances the same id will be run. How can I do so? I can't seem to figure out the logic.

P.S `System.out.print(id)` is a line of test code, the output is one chunk of IDs.

**Edit: the logic would work something like SQL's count function, but I'm not using SQL, I just need it in pure java

Comment: You can maintain a map for id and their count just outside the for loop

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Normally a hashmap wouldn't allow an id (key) to be present multiple times.

Comment: do you mind sharing maybe just a pseudocode on how it is gonna work? @SacJn

Comment: Do you just want to know all ids that are duplicated? Do you need the counts as well?

Comment: @Thomas the id is passed in as a parameter from another class, also in a for loop! so for the codes I posted the id will be appearing as the parameter that is passed in.

Comment: @Bohemian yes that's about it! because I'll be using the result for other functions as well, so i need the number of times it has been duplicated, not just true or false type of situation.

Comment: What happens if id 5 has obj1 and obj2 and id 6 has obj3? You output (5,obj1) and increase that id by one, so you output (6,obj2), which later on is going to clash with (6,obj3)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos if I understand your question properly, the objects in the ID don't matter, I just want to know as the loop goes how many times the same IDs have appeared.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure I fully get your problem but you might try Google Guava's `Multimap` which can store multiple values per key. That way you could collect all users for one id and check how many users there are for each id.

Comment: A `HashMap` can only contain one object against each key. If you want to store more than one object you need a `MultiMap` of some kind. Also, you will need to count them as athey are put into the map, not when you pint them.

Comment: @Thomas true so I would maintain only the frequency for that id. So a `map<Id, List <Objects> ` if I understand OP's question right

Comment: And where does the `id` come from? Is it passed to a method, or are users/ids stored in a collection somewhere? It looks like you map is a `Map<Integer, List<UserObject>>` - is the list size where the count comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand it correctly, but if you want to count elements in the HashMap, you can try something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "A");
    map.put("2", "B");
    map.put("3", "C");
    map.put("4", "B");
    map.put("5", "B");
    map.put("6", "C");

    System.out.println(count("B", map)); // output is 3
}

static int count(String id, Map<String, String> map) {
    int i = 0;
    for (String val : map.values()) {
        if (id.equals(val))
            i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

EDIT: If you want to wrap the funcionality where every time you touch particular value, counter increments, you can achieve it by this approach.

```
public class IdHandler {

    Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public int count(String id) {
        return count.get(id);
    }

    public void export(Map<String, String> map) {
        for (String value : map.values()) {
            System.out.println(value);

            if (!count.containsKey(value)) {
                count.put(value, 1);
            } else {
                int i = count.get(value);
                count.put(value, ++i);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "A");
    map.put("2", "B");
    map.put("3", "C");
    map.put("4", "B");
    map.put("5", "B");
    map.put("6", "C");

    IdHandler id = new IdHandler();
    id.export(map);

    System.out.println(id.count("B")); // output is 3
    System.out.println(id.count("C")); // output is 2
}
```